# What should I have to do to publish React Native Expo App?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting this error in cmd while publishing the App. How to resolve this? Please suggest me if anyone of you have any idea.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1126:14)

I am using this version expo-cli 3.2.3

Comment: What is your expo-cli version?

Comment: Please update your question with expo environment informations.

Comment: I am using this version expo-cli 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first step update expo-cli into the latest version and try "expo start -c" to clear cache when it launching.

If it not fixed, delete '.expo' and and retry.

(In the Expo repository also have several issues on this issue and they still work on it.)

[an issue reported on expo repository](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5789)

[an issue discussed on expo forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/econnrefused-127-0-0-1-19001-usual-fixes-not-helping-resolved/27415)

Comment: D:\ReactNative\MyProject>expo build:android -t apk
Checking if there is a build in progress...


? Would you like to upload a keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us handle it! :)
 false
Publishing to channel 'default'...
Building iOS bundle
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

This is what I am getting

Comment: Just delete .expo folder and then 1). "expo start" 2). Open another tab 3)."expo build:android" or "expo build:ios"